# Is there a way to auto fill on another life with a similar equation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In the example picture I uploaded, I want to do the same equation for the other lines in excel where I put "Here" without having to type it all again and then dragging it to auto fill.

Example, I want "Here" on the bottom left line to take the 6 and divide it by the 5.
On the top right, 56/5, etc etc.

[image]

Comment: *without having to type it all again and then dragging it to auto fill* That's how Excel works. You can copy/paste the formula but anyways selecting where to paste is equal to dragging so no, you can't achieve as you wish